# c++ general `flatten` of container of containers

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I'm interested in to implement a general `flatten` of a container of containers

In order to simplify, I will use my own containers. The main reason of that is that the standard containers receive an additional template parameter for the allocator, what does more complicated for me to write the operation. So, consider the containers `Vector<T>`, `List<T>`, etc as reminiscent to the standard containers, except that they do not require the allocator.

Now, I have an operational `flatten` operation until four levels as follows:

```
template <typename T,
      template <typename> class Container1,
      template <typename> class Container2>
List<T> flatten(const Container1<Container2<T>> & c)
{
  List<T> ret;
  for (auto & l : c)
    for (auto & item : l)
      ret.push_back(item);

  return ret;
}

template <typename T,
      template <typename> class Container1,
      template <typename> class Container2,
      template <typename> class Container3>
List<T>
flatten(const Container1<Container2<Container3<T>>> & c)
{
  List<T> ret;
  for (auto & l : c)
    ret.splice(ret.end(), flatten(l));

  return ret;
}

template <typename T,
          template <typename> class Container1,
          template <typename> class Container2,
          template <typename> class Container3,
          template <typename> class Container4>
    List<T> flatten // and so on for more levels ...
```

My questions are:

1. Does exist a more concise, and especially, general way which allows any quantity of levels, probably based on more elegant metaprogramming, or may be using macros, for writing this operation?
2. If the previous question is affirmative, then could someone summarise how could be?
3. Some way for applying at least this technique for the standard containers? As I said, what has complicated my `flatten`  version on standard containers was that these ones receive the allocator as template parameter.

Comment: "or maybe macros" - no. Macro's work on tokens, not on types.

Comment: I suspect your detection of "container types" is a bit loose, as it seems to look for any template that takes one type. Is `std::complex<double>` a container with two elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by recursively flattening a container:

```
template<typename Container, typename T>
void flatten_impl(Container const& c, List<T>& out)
{
   for(auto const& elem : c) flatten(elem, out);
}
```

Obviously, like any recursion, you need to terminate this recursion as well:

```
template<typename Elem, typename T>
void flatten_impl(Elem e, List<T>& out)
{
    out.push_back(e);
}
```

and as these are now ambiguous, you need to resolve the ambiguity:

```
template<typename Elem, typename T>
void flatten_impl(Elem e, List<T>& out, ...)
{
    out.push_back(e);
}
template<typename Container, typename T>
std::void_t<typename Container::value_type> flatten_impl(Container const& c, List<T>& out)
{
   for(auto const& elem : c) flatten(elem, out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T>
struct LooksLikeContainer {
  struct Yes{};
  struct No {Yes yes[2];};

  template <typename U>
  static auto test(U* p) ->
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof(std::begin(*p)) != 0, Yes>::type;

  static No test(...);

  static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test(static_cast<T*>(nullptr))) == sizeof(Yes);
};

template <typename In, typename Out>
auto flatten(const In& in, Out* out) ->
  typename std::enable_if<!LooksLikeContainer<In>::value>::type;

template <typename In, typename Out>
auto flatten(const In& in, Out* out) ->
  typename std::enable_if<LooksLikeContainer<In>::value>::type {
  for (auto& el : in) {
      flatten(el, out);
  }
}

template <typename In, typename Out>
auto flatten(const In& in, Out* out) ->
  typename std::enable_if<!LooksLikeContainer<In>::value>::type {
  out->push_back(in);
}
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/GTQL8692)

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views), you may use `ranges::view::join`, something like:

```
namespace detail
{
    struct overload_priority_low {};
    struct overload_priority_high : overload_priority_low {};

    template <typename R>
    R flatten(R&& r, overload_priority_low)
    {
        return std::forward<R>(r);
    }

    template <typename R>
    auto flatten(R&& r, overload_priority_high)
    -> decltype(flatten(std::forward<R>(r) | ranges::view::join, overload_priority_high{}))
    {
        return flatten(std::forward<R>(r) | ranges::view::join, overload_priority_high{});
    }

}

template <typename R>
auto flatten(R&& r)
{
    return detail::flatten(std::forward<R>(r), detail::overload_priority_high{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/790c46d3edd81f8c)